# An event for cleaning up Angular Router resolved data?

Tags: angular, angular-router

**How / where / when can I clean up resolved items (e.g. observable data) provided by Angular's Router?**

Angular's `Router` `resolve`s data to provide to components, but there is no symmetric `unresolve` call available that I can see. The `Router` knows when it is done with resolved data (internally, `advanceRoute` is one aspect of this). However it does not advertise such events in a way that resolvers can see, since resolvers receive an immutable snapshot rather than any event stream.

Here's my current (incomplete) strategy:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, router: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let vm = RouteValue.useActiveProvider<ViewModelFactoryBase>(route).value(this, (k) => route.paramMap.get(k));
    this.uponLeaving(route, () => vm.disconnect());
    return vm.connect();
}

private uponLeaving(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, action: () => void) {
    let url = [""].concat(...route.pathFromRoot
        .filter(r => r.url instanceof Array)
        .map(r => r.url.map(s => s.path)))
        .join('/');
    this.router.events
        .filter(e => (
            e instanceof NavigationEnd ||
            e instanceof NavigationCancel ||
            e instanceof NavigationError
        ) && !(this.router.isActive(url, false)))
        .first()
        .subscribe(action);
}
```

You may notice multiple problems with this:

1. it doesn't account for query parameters or aux routes because `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is difficult to transform to something useful (e.g. `Router.isActive` requires an `UrlTree`).
2. it is weakly-coupled to angular's route resolver via a string. snapshots are replaced and may or may not reuse previously-resolved data.
3. it doesn't use angular's active URL strategies (which are configurable and might change). note `RouterStateSnapshot.url` represents the final destination, not the current node.

There are other issues with it, too. What would be ideal would be to bind to the `ActivatedRoute.data` Observable's `next` and `complete` events, but that isn't possible from `resolve`. A `RouteLeave` event, or something similar, might also work, but there seems to be no allowance currently made for this need.

I've considered switching to a hand-off type strategy - where my viewmodels are resolved to `Shared` observables, instead of `Published` - then monitor `ActivationEnd` (or the same navigation completion events in the code above) to release the resolver's reference count on the resolved viewmodel. Now clean-up happens a layer deeper. That removes the simple connection management symmetry I'd prefer, and also gets quite complicated at a the `Component` level, where components must now work harder to understand the router, which probably should not be their concern.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? A resolver typically simply uses HttpClient (directly or indirectly by calling a service) to return an Observable<SomeData>. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sure, thanks for asking. Abstractly, I'm resolving and providing data to my component that needs to be cleaned up when it expires. Specifically, it does more than simply uses HttpClient: It is a live data subscription. Resolve here is essential in order to postpone navigation until the Observable is hot. Another method to delay navigation would also be acceptable, but as an aside I don't expect a solution there as we've already tried that approach many times.

Comment: If you place a close vote for reason "unclear", especially on a question with so much effort made clarifying a complex issue, please state why you found it unclear so the asker can improve the question.